# How to allow multiple Python projects to use each other's packages?

Tags: python, module, export, pythonpath

I have a situation where I have three Python projects, each with their own repositories, and each with configuration files like .pylintrc file at their root.

```
Project A
- .pylintrc
- .git
- src/
-- __init__.py
-- hello.py

Project B
- .pylintrc
- .git
- src/
-- __init__.py
-- there.py

Project C
- .pylintrc
- .git
- src/
-- __init__.py
-- general_kenobi.py
```

I would like to be able to use packages and modules from any of the projects. So for example, in ProjectA/src/hello.py I would like to be able to do

```
import ProjectB.src.there
```

Is this possible?
I've spent all morning trying to put pylintrc in an enclosing folder called PROJECT.
Currently my PYTHONPATH variable looks like this:

```
/Documents/Sites/PROJECT:/Documents/Sites/PROJECT/ProjectA:/Documents/Sites/PROJECT/ProjectB
```

However, I can't get this to work. It's important to keep the repositories separate, but doing so seems to make this kind of importing impossible.

If anyone can point me in the direction of a solution I'd appreciate it.

Comment: create wheel file of all these project or create python package for all of these 3

Comment: Thanks-  reading up on wheel files now

Comment: I assume you have more than one file in each project.
Do you also import files from within the same project?
The answer to this question is kind of important.

If yes, then with your current directory structure things can get really messy, especially if any of your modules contain global variables.

I would then suggest a modified directory structure.

Comment: another question: Do you use virtualenv or any similiar tool, to allow having your own python module setup for each project?

If yes, then you might think about transforming each project's into a python module,
(changing directory structure slightly and providing a setup.py)

You could then `pip install -e` each module into a commonly shared virtualenv

Comment: Hi @gelonida, thanks for your replies. Yes there is importing of files within the same project. I think the best thing I can do is keep the repos separate, and install them using conda (my env manager) as you suggested in your second comment. Many thanks.